# How to create apps with live text calculations/processing similar Calca and Taskpaper

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Any suggestions where I would start to create apps similar to Soulver, Calca, and TaskPaper.

I'm planning to create a simple text-based project management app that handles scheduling, assignments, etc.

Is there any framework or library that I can leverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find `NSExpression` useful as it can perform several mathematical operations:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"5 - 2**5"];
id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```